# Wrapping tags around multiple paragraphs

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, emmet

Is there a command or extension that can wrap tags around multiple paragraphs of selected text?

I know **"Emmet: Wrap with Abbreviation"** lets you wrap a tag around a selected block of text. But I'd like to select multiple paragraphs of text and wrap a tag around each paragraph in one go rather for select each paragraph and run the Emmet command for each paragraph.

For example, if I select/highlight these two paragraphs...

```
I am the first paragraph.

I am the second paragraph.
```

... I'd like to run one command that wraps both paragraphs in a tag (e.g. `<p>`), just like the Emmet Wrap w/Abbreviation command does.

```
<p>I am the first paragraph.</p>

<p>I am the second paragraph.</p>
```

Comment: Use Multi Cursor to select each line separate then Wrap abbreviation, Now `p` tags will add indentation, so multi cursor `cut - add p tag - paste` could be an alternative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap individual lines using `*` marker: https://docs.emmet.io/actions/wrap-with-abbreviation/#wrapping-individual-lines